# how to solve ionic application 401 unauthorized error when accessing audio file through url ( audio file is recorded via media capture plugin )?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am having one weird issue. I am recording audio through media capture plugin and put path in audio tag from retrieved data. I am using fullPath property of recorded file on ios. but it is not working.

This is url request information from safari debugging window.

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC4Fz.png)

Here is another application where same logic is working.

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQwg3.png)

I know there is only one difference in referer information. but i am not able to solve this.

EDIT!!!!

Main issue was cordova-plugin-ionic-webview version, downgrading from 2.2.0 to 1.2.1 solved issue. Can someone please explain in little bit more detail?